# Polymer - How to trigger an action on an element embedded in a Polymer element from the page the element is in?

Tags: javascript, treeview, polymer

Suppose I created a Polymer element that had some other elements embedded in it.  I then place this element on a page.  From the Javascript that is in the page that contains the Polymer element, how would I manipulate the embedded elements that are inside the Polymer element?

For example, what if I created an element named `<treeview>`, that internally uses `<ul>`, `<li>`, and `<paper-checkbox>` elements to create a treeview hierarchy.  I then add this control to a page.  If each of the `<paper-checkbox>` elements inside the `<treeview>` control have a unique id, how can I make a call from the page to toggle a specific `<paper-checkbox>` if I know the unique id of the element I want to toggle?

I tried exposing a function on the `<treeview>` element that I could call to set the property.  For example, `function toggleTreeviewItem(id)`.  But when i try calling toggleTreeviewItem from the page containing the `<treeview>` it never seems to work.  I think the reason that it fails is because inside `toggleTreeviewItem`, I'm not able to get a handle to the `<paper-checkbox>` controls that could be embedded in nested `<template is="dom-repeat">` elements.

Here is a very simplified version of the Javascript for the `<treeview>` control. As you can see in the `toggleTreeviewItem` function, I tried three different ways of getting a handle to the specific `<paper-checkbox>` item that I'm trying to manipulate.  None seemed to work for me.  I think I'm probably missing something that is obvious.

```
Polymer({
  is: 'treeview',

  properties: {
    someProperty: {
      type: String,
      value: "Hello Yo!"
    },

  },  // End of Properties

  observers: [
  ],

  ready: function () {
    // does some stuff here...
  },


  toggleTreeviewItem: function(id) {
    console.log('Entered method: toggleTreeviewItem', id);

    try {
      var checkbox = document.getElementById('treeview-item-' + id);
      // var checkbox = document.querySelector("#treeview-item-" + id);
      // var checkbox = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#treeview-item-" + id);
      console.log('checkbox', checkbox);
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;

    } catch (ex) {
      console.log('Name:', ex.name);
      console.log('Message:', ex.message);
      console.log('Stack:', ex.stack);
    } finally {
      console.log('Exited method: toggleTreeviewItem');
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` and `document.querySelector()` (and similar native DOM functions) cannot pierce the shadow boundary of your custom element, so they wouldn't be able to find the inner treeview item. In your case, you should use [`this.$$()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-$$) (Polymer syntactic sugar for `this.querySelector()`) in `toggleTreeviewItem()`:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',

    _toggleChk2: function() {
      this.toggleTreeviewItem(2);
    },

    toggleTreeviewItem: function(id) {
      const chkbox = this.$$(`#treeview-item-${id}`);
      chkbox.checked = !chkbox.checked;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  <script>
    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      var foo = document.querySelector('x-foo');
      foo.toggleTreeviewItem(3);
    });
  </script>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[1,2,3,4]">
        <paper-checkbox id$="treeview-item-[[index]]">Checkbox [[index]]</paper-checkbox>
      </template>
      <button on-tap="_toggleChk2">Toggle Checkbox 2</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zKQKpj?editors=1010)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think it solved my problem... for the most part. I'm still experiencing some strange behavior. I added your suggestion in an event listener for the `WebComponentsReady` event and it still returned null for the checkbox, even if I used the `this.$$()` syntax. But then I added a button to the page that was using my polymer element and had it's click event call the same event `toggleTreeviewItem(id)` that the `WebComponentsReady` was calling. This worked! It also worked when I changed `toggleTreeviewItem` to use `document.getElementById`. Ideas on why the 2nd way worked?

Comment: The only difference I can think of between my component and your example is that my component is in a separate file and has to be HTML Imported into the page that is using it.

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I just got around to adding a Plunker. I've figured out that when the `dom-repeat` is populated by an `iron-ajax` response, the `toggleTreeviewItem` isn't able to retrieve the `paper-checkbox` properly in the `WebComponentsReady` event. If the `dom-repeat` is populated by a static array, it IS able to retrieve the `paper-checkbox` properly. It always works on the button click

Maybe the binding to the dom elements hasn't completed the asynchronous response from the iron-ajax when the`WebComponentsReady`fired?

[Plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/cZn0u6UNiR9QVQbQpgT7?p=preview)

Comment: As you guessed, the `WebComponentsReady` event does not indicate that the response of `<iron-ajax>` has been received. If you want to toggle the checkbox upon responses, you would need to bind a handler to the [`<iron-ajax>.response`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#event-response) event.

Comment: So, I added an event for the iron-ajax.response event. I then had it fire an event called `onTreeviewLoaded` so that the index.html page can listen for that event and try to call the method to click the checkbox. This still returned null for the checkbox.

After that I figured that maybe I have to manually cause the dom-repeat to refresh.  So I added an `id='youtube-results'` to the dom-repeat and then called `document.getElementById('youtube-results').render();` right before I fired the onTreeviewLoaded event.  This worked!
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cZn0u6UNiR9QVQbQpgT7?p=preview)